# Sum Columns in Child Table Based on Column in Parent Table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I am trying to use lambda to select the sum of the (Quantity * Value) in table B where column IsChecked in Table A is true.

**Table A**

A_ID  (Int) **Primary KEY**
IsChecked (Boolean)

**Table B**
B_ID  (Int)
A_ID  (Int)   **Foregin KEY to Table A**
Quantity  (Int)
Value(Int)

My worthless attempt(sorry its beyond my knowledge):

```
_context.TableA.Where(i => i.IsChecked == True).Include(i => i.TableB).Sum(i => i.Price * i.Quantity))
```

This is the sql query:

```
SELECT SUM(Value * QUANTITY)  FROM TableB JOIN TableA ON TableA.A_ID = TableB.A_ID WHERE TableA.IsChecked = 'true'
```

Comment: why you are using `Include` ? where do you use them ? do you have any `navigation` between `TableA` and `TableB`?

Comment: Do you have any navigation properties going from `Table B` back to `Table A`?  That would allow `_context.TableB.Include(i => i.TableA).Where(w => w.TableA.IsChecked).Sum(s => s.Price * s.Quantity)`

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yes that the "A_ID" column as shown in the table structure.  I will edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, but this is an Entity Framework context right?  Can you post your POCO model definitions and any model builder code if this is the case?

Comment: @BrendanGreen  I see what you mean now.  Your comment is correct can you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a navigation property from `Table B` back to `Table A`, you can start off at `Table B` like this:

```
_context.TableB
    .Include(i => i.TableA)
    .Where(w => w.TableA.IsChecked)
    .Sum(s => s.Price * s.Quantity)
```

Note that the above does not check if `A_ID` in `Table B` is null.

Comment: Yip that works, thanks.  I got what you meant with the nav property once I went back to my model.